# How to register an event for when a user has a new tweet?

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I am looking through the Tweepy API and not quite sure how to find the event to register for when a user either send or receives a new tweet.  I looked into the Streaming API but it seems like that is only sampling the Twitter fire house and not really meant for looking at one indvidual user.  What I am trying to do is have my program update whenever something happens to the user.  Essentially what a user would see if they were in their account on the twitter homepage.  So my question is: What is the method or event I should be looking for in the Tweepy API to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the .filter function then filtered for the user I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about *tweepy*, but you should really look into Twitter's API Document [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/user-streams), which describes your need directly.

And I took a look at *tweepy* but don't seem to find it support the `userstream` series of Twitter API, maybe you have to wrap it yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any event based pub-sub exposed by twitter. You just have to do the long polling.